# KDB: How to match string of possible dates with rows of table?

Tags: string, string-matching, kdb

I essentially just want to create a date column that represents the date of the filename.

My table `filesInDir` is just a single column and 4 rows called `filepath`:

```
":..\..\code\products\Q\ExtData\CIBC\availability\Global\EquityOnly\daily\bnyMellon_inventory\push_list_20190314_040253_Equity.csv"
":..\..\code\products\Q\ExtData\CIBC\availability\Global\EquityOnly\daily\bnyMellon_inventory\push_list_20190314_040306_Equity.csv"
":..\..\code\products\Q\ExtData\CIBC\availability\Global\EquityOnly\daily\bnyMellon_inventory\push_list_20190311_040321_Bond.csv"
":..\..\code\products\Q\ExtData\CIBC\availability\Global\EquityOnly\daily\bnyMellon_inventory\push_list_20190312_999999_Cash.csv"
```

I also have a list of possible dates, `2019.03.12 2019.03.11 2019.03.14`. How can match the list of dates with the rows of the table above so that I can get a new column that specifies that date value that matched with the filepath string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how you parse the filePath to get the date, Please note as "\" is the escape sign so you need to write as "\\" instead that or directly retrieve the string from system command.

Created table

```
filesInDir:([]filePaths:(":..\\..\\code\\products\\Q\\ExtData\\CIBC\\availability\\Global\\EquityOnly\\daily\\bnyMellon_inventory\\push_list_20190314_040253_Equity.csv";
":..\\..\\code\\products\\Q\\ExtData\\CIBC\\availability\\Global\\EquityOnly\\daily\\bnyMellon_inventory\\push_list_20190314_040306_Equity.csv";
":..\\..\\code\\products\\Q\\ExtData\\CIBC\\availability\\Global\\EquityOnly\\daily\\bnyMellon_inventory\\push_list_20190311_040321_Bond.csv";
":..\\..\\code\\products\\Q\\ExtData\\CIBC\\availability\\Global\\EquityOnly\\daily\\bnyMellon_inventory\\push_list_20190312_999999_Cash.csv"))
```

Create the date column

```
update date:{"D"$("_"vs last "\\" vs x)[2]} each filePaths from `filesInDir
```

> I also have a list of possible dates, 2019.03.12 2019.03.11 2019.03.14. How can match the list of dates with the rows of the table above so that I can get a new column that specifies that date value that matched with the filepath string.

Can you give some example illustration on that? Not clear about what you intend and expect to see

If you just want let say a "Flag" column indicating whether the date in the records match with the dateRange, you can simply use a `in` to match that.

```
dateRange:2019.03.12 2019.03.11 2019.03.14
update match:date in dateRange from `filesInDir
```

This will be the output:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

If all your file paths follow the same format as your example ones,you can create a date column pretty easily doing:

```
update date:"D"$8#'103_'filePaths from filesInDir
```

Then match with your dates using this column.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach using `0:`

```
update date:raze("   D";"_")0:filePaths from filesInDir
```

It is dependent on the occurrences of `_` in your filepaths